# Typescript Hash Member arithmetical restrictions

Tags: typescript

Can I define somehow a type in typescript which apply as well arythmeical constraints to object props
E.g.

```
type RestrictedObject = {
a: number,
b: number,
}
```

so that `a` % `b` = 0

Comment: You can't. The only thing you can do is using getters and setters and do a validation on setting a new value

Answer (score 1):

No, that would require runtime checking, which is out of bounds for TypeScript.

You can define an object with accessor properties to enforce the relationship:

```js
class Restricted {
    #a: number;
    #b: number;

    static #valid(a: number, b: number): boolean {
        return a % b === 0;
    }

    constructor(a: number,  b:number) {
        if (Restricted.#valid(a, b)) {
            throw new Error(`The values of 'a' and 'b' must be such that 'a % b' is 0; ${a} and ${b} don't fit`);
        }
        this.#a = a;
        this.#b = b;
    }

    get a() {
        return this.#a;
    }
    set a(value) {
        if (this.#b !== null) {
            if (Restricted.#valid(value, this.#b)) {
                throw new Error(`The value of 'a' cannot be ${value} when 'b' is ${this.#b}`);
            }
        }
        this.#a = value;
    }

    get b() {
        return this.#b;
    }
    set b(value) {
        if (this.#a !== null) {
            if (Restricted.#valid(this.#a, value)) {
                throw new Error(`The value of 'b' cannot be ${value} when 'a' is ${this.#a}`);
            }
        }
        this.#b = value;
    }
}
```

Side note: The above uses JavaScript's native private fields and private static methods, which are specified parts of the language now, but you could use TypeScript's `private` instead if you liked.